# Rails Apnotic OpenSSL alert certificate expired error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send Apple Push Notifications from a Rails app using the Apnotic gem.

I get the following error when I run `@ios_client.push(note)`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-http2-0.18.4/lib/net-http2/client.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in ensure_open'
    4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-http2-0.18.4/lib/net-http2/client.rb:142:in `socket_loop'
    3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-http2-0.18.4/lib/net-http2/client.rb:142:in `loop'
    2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-http2-0.18.4/lib/net-http2/client.rb:145:in `block in socket_loop'
    1: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182:in `read_nonblock'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182:in `sysread_nonblock': SSL_read: sslv3 alert certificate expired (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I believe my certificate that I obtained from the Apple Developer account is not expired (I tested by creating a new one), so is there something wrong with my OpenSSL installation?

I get the same error locally and on Heroku. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your certificate, open it by your desktop environment and see if the date is between `not valid before` and `not valid after`.

[image: paste key to file and save with .pem]

First save your key with .pem

[image: key detail]
If you are using mac, click the file just saved and press space bar to check valid date

Comment: Thanks! Even though I created a new certificate my app configuration was still pointing to a different old certificate.